# Xampp shell refuses to respond to commands once server starts

Tags: windows, apache, shell, xampp

I've been searching high and low for this one, figuring it to be a common noob problem, but nothing. I saw an oblique reference somewhere that xampp's shell won't accept ctrl-c to close an operation but I'd like to confirm.

As it is, I'm running Xampp on a win7 machine and it's set up with the default apache mysql combo. Which is all fine. Except that the command line stops receiving commands once I start a server. So if I want to run another command I've gotta exit the xampp command line and restart it.

Is there a way to abort shell scripts in the xampp shell or is it just a product of the environment it's running in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to consider this solved.

While Xampp locks up once you start a server instance. It's possible to run a server directly through the windows normal command line Start->Run->cmd, while doing other xampp stuff in the xampp shell.